# What can be reason for getting "execute permission denied" in cronjob in UNIX?

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have a shellscript which can be successfully executed in UNIX with command `sh Shell_script.sh`; but I want it to run automatically. So I just configured a cronjob to run the script using `crontab -e`.

The cronjob added is below:

```
0 7-23 * * * * /home/folder1/folder2/Shell_script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I want it to be executed hourly from 7AM to 11PM every day.

My shell script has a she-bang `#!/bin/bash`.
I am getting a mail every hour with the content:

> Your "cron" job on servername
>   * /home/folder1/folder2/Shell_script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
>
> produced the following output:
>
> sh: +61: execute permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra `*` in your cron line which is interpreting as Username. Once you delete it it will be fine executed.

also consider if your Shell_script.sh is not executable, you need run with `sh` (if it's written in sh) or `bash` if it's bash written.

```
0 7-23 * * * bash /home/folder1/folder2/Shell_script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have edited my cronjob. Hope it works in the next execution.

Comment: Thanks and Welcome. One things that I noticed you are as a new user in Unix.stackexchange.com community and other SO had several questions without accepting the answer. considering please take your time and [accept the one which solved your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). thank you again

Comment: Will I get any mail while running cronjob if my script is not executable?

Comment: if you run with `bash your_script.sh` you no need to worry about executable. you can make it executable with `chmod +x your_script.sh`. I never used cron to sending mail, so not sure if it will send mail if was not able to execute, but that's sounds it should be

Comment: Thank you so much....Its working fine now....Also used `chmod +x your_script.sh`.

Comment: Since the job was added with `crontab -e`, it's not the system crontab.  This means that `*` is not interpreted as a username.